# read route parameter in redux angular4

Tags: angular, redux

I am creating an angular4 multi-language application using Redux. 
I want to read the language parameter from the URL so I can set the redux variable.

Redux:

```
export class LanguageActions {
  private locale = '';

  constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>, private router: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.router.params.subscribe(params => this.locale = params.lang != null ? params.lang : '');
   // the language is always ''.
   }

  getCurrentLanguage() {
    return this.locale;
  }
}
```

Routing:

```
const routes: Routes =
[
  { path: ':lang/search', component: SearchResultListComponent },
];
```

URL:

> http://localhost/en-us/search

the language come always as null from the redux

why? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Use ActivatedRoute and sucscribe to it

```
export class LanguageActions implements OnInit {

    lang: string;
    private sub: any;

    constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.lang= params['lang'];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: the result came as undefined. it is a redux not a normal component